# Why it can't update a database when I click on button which contains update code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a DataGridView which shows list of items retrieved from a database. Few Textboxes which are updated with values of clicked row and a Update(btnAzuriraj) button which create instance of class and then updates DB and refresh the Data grid view.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {

        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        tbID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        tbIme.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        tbPrezime.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        tbAdresa.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        tbTelefon.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "0")
        {
            cbPol.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cbPol.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
        dtbDatumRodjenja.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
    }
    //pacijent = new Pacijent(tbID.Text, tbIme.Text, tbPrezime.Text, tbAdresa.Text, tbTelefon.Text, cbPol.SelectedIndex, dtbDatumRodjenja.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());
}

private void btnAzuriraj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pacijent = new Pacijent(tbID.Text, tbIme.Text, tbPrezime.Text, tbAdresa.Text, tbTelefon.Text, cbPol.SelectedIndex, dtbDatumRodjenja.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());

    try
    {
        konekcija.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("UPDATE pacijent SET ime=@Ime, prezime=@Prezime, adresa=@Adresa, telefon=@Telefon, pol=@Pol, datumRodjenja=@DatumRodjenja WHERE id=@ID", konekcija))
        {
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Ime", pacijent.Ime));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Prezime", pacijent.Prezime));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Adresa", pacijent.Adresa));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Telefon", pacijent.Telefon));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Pol", pacijent.Pol));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DatumRodjenja", pacijent.DatumRodjenja));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ID", pacijent.Id));

            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ocistiPodatke();
            ucitajListuPacijenata();
            MessageBox.Show("Podaci o pacijentu " + pacijent.Ime + " " + pacijent.Prezime + " su uspesno azurirani.");
        }
    }
```

And all this is working well, but notice the commented part in Cellclick method. When I want to change place where it instances Pacijent class to be in Cellclick method instead of btnAzuriraj_Click it won't update the database with newest values. Why?

Basically I want to instance a class and fill it with different values every time I click the row in DataGridView not only when I want to update DB. I want to do this because I want to use class values for something else not only for DB update.

**Question update**. I even tried to instance a class inside `e.RowIndex >=0` statement. And Checked if it actually stores and retrieves values from a class object. And all that is working fine except it won't update the database.

Comment: _it won't work._ is not a helpful problem description!

Comment: @TaW, I've updated the description and question.

Comment: If it needs to update the database then you need to also include the code in CellClick to update that you used in button click (unless Pacijent is doing that for each time it is created).

Comment: Ok I think that a title is now wrong as from suggestions from others I realised that it instances a class well but the problem is updating the database after you click btnAzuriraj

Comment: Update code works when I make instance of a class inside button click method. But when I make instance inside cell click method it won't work. I've tested if button click method can actually retrieve values from pacijent object and the results are okay.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean 'it won't work' ? `pacijent` is not instantiated - got nulls instead of some proper values on its properties?

Maybe it is because you instantiate `pacijent` out of the

`if (e.RowIndex >= 0) 
{ 
}`

clause, while initialization of the data used in `Pacijent` constructor is done in `if() { }` clause.

Comment: I tried to instance class inside that statement also. When I say it won't work I mean that it won't update database by newest values.

Comment: You are using the `pacijent` object to update its values inside database, right? maybe your ID property of the `pacijent` object is 0 and thus the UPDATE query is not working? Check if `pacijent.ID` is not equal to 0 when you run update db query.

Comment: Yes to update values from pacijent object. I made output to MessageBox inside btnAzuriraj to check value of pacijent.ID and it is working properly and shows the right value depending on clicked row.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that I forgot to edit to the newest values from textboxes inside a class instance. So it should look like this.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {

        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        tbID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        tbIme.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        tbPrezime.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        tbAdresa.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        tbTelefon.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "0")
        {
            cbPol.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cbPol.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
        dtbDatumRodjenja.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        pacijent = new Pacijent(tbID.Text, tbIme.Text, tbPrezime.Text, tbAdresa.Text, tbTelefon.Text, cbPol.SelectedIndex, dtbDatumRodjenja.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());
    }

}

private void btnAzuriraj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //pacijent = new Pacijent(tbID.Text, tbIme.Text, tbPrezime.Text, tbAdresa.Text, tbTelefon.Text, cbPol.SelectedIndex, dtbDatumRodjenja.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());

    pacijent.Id = tbID.Text;
    pacijent.Ime = tbIme.Text;
    pacijent.Prezime = tbPrezime.Text;
    pacijent.Adresa = tbAdresa.Text;
    pacijent.Pol = cbPol.SelectedIndex;
    pacijent.DatumRodjenja = dtbDatumRodjenja.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();

    try
    {
        konekcija.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("UPDATE pacijent SET ime=@Ime, prezime=@Prezime, adresa=@Adresa, telefon=@Telefon, pol=@Pol, datumRodjenja=@DatumRodjenja WHERE id=@ID", konekcija))
        {
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Ime", pacijent.Ime));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Prezime", pacijent.Prezime));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Adresa", pacijent.Adresa));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Telefon", pacijent.Telefon));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Pol", pacijent.Pol));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DatumRodjenja", pacijent.DatumRodjenja));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ID", pacijent.Id));

            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ocistiPodatke();
            ucitajListuPacijenata();
            MessageBox.Show("Podaci o pacijentu " + pacijent.Ime + " " + pacijent.Prezime + " su uspesno azurirani.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
}
```